# Как реализовать данный интерфейс приложения Android?

Tags: android

Добрый день. 1) С помощью чего можно реализовать данный интерфейс ?

[image: Интерфейс привью]

Comment: разделите ваш вопрос на 2, как положено. По первому вопросу = `GridView`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вы можете реализовать такой интерфейс при помощи `GridView`, и кнопки *Отправить* под ним